# How to do alternating rows in Angular Select dropdown

Tags: angularjs

I can't seem to find an example on how to do add alternating rows in the select directive.  I tried ng-class-odd / even with no luck.

Here's the control I'm trying to do it on:

```
<select id="pendingInvites" style="width: 85%; height: 300px;" ng-options="invite.id as invite.userName for invite in PendingInviteList"
                            multiple
                            ng-model="user.pendingUserName"></select>
```

I also tried the class="$index % 2 === 0" approach.  It seems to be getting set once at the parent level, but not on the options tag the directive generates.

How can I alternate colors in my generated options tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with pure css:

```
option:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #F00;
}
```

in a css file or a style block should turn all the even options red